# "current" in Linux kernel code

Tags: linux, pointers, linux-kernel

As I was going through the below chunk of Linux char driver code, I found the structure pointer `current` in `printk`.

I want to know what structure the `current` is pointing to and its complete elements.

What purpose does this structure serve?

```
ssize_t sleepy_read (struct file *filp, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *pos)
{
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "process %i (%s) going to sleep\n",
    current->pid, current->comm);
    wait_event_interruptible(wq, flag != 0);
    flag = 0;
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "awoken %i (%s)\n", current->pid, current->comm);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like it's a structure that refers to the process that made the system call.

Comment: Try googling for `annotated linux kernel`, you should find some helpful resources.

Comment: http://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/current

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is a pointer to the current process ie, the process which has issued the system call.

From the [docs](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch02.html):

> **The Current Process**
>
> Although kernel modules don't execute sequentially as applications do,
>   most actions performed by the kernel are related to a specific
>   process. Kernel code can know the current process driving it by
>   accessing the global item current, a pointer to struct task_struct,
>   which as of version 2.4 of the kernel is declared in
>   `<asm/current.h>`, included by `<linux/sched.h>`. **The current pointer
>   refers to the user process currently executing. During the execution
>   of a system call, such as open or read, the current process is the one
>   that invoked the call.** Kernel code can use process-specific
>   information by using current, if it needs to do so. An example of this
>   technique is presented in "Access Control on a Device File", in
>   Chapter 5, "Enhanced Char Driver Operations".
>
> Actually, current is not properly a global variable any more, like it
>   was in the first Linux kernels. The developers optimized access to the
>   structure describing the current process by hiding it in the stack
>   page. You can look at the details of current in `<asm/current.h>`. While
>   the code you'll look at might seem hairy, we must keep in mind that
>   Linux is an SMP-compliant system, and a global variable simply won't
>   work when you are dealing with multiple CPUs. The details of the
>   implementation remain hidden to other kernel subsystems though, and a
>   device driver can just include  and refer to the
>   current process.
>
> From a module's point of view, current is just like the external
>   reference printk. A module can refer to current wherever it sees fit.
>   For example, the following statement prints the process ID and the
>   command name of the current process by accessing certain fields in
>   struct task_struct:
>
> ```
>  printk("The process is \"%s\" (pid %i)\n",
>   current->comm, current->pid);
> ```
>
> The command name stored in current->comm is the base name of the
>   program file that is being executed by the current process.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the complete structure the "current" is pointing to

```
task_struct
Each task_struct data structure describes a process or task in the system.

struct task_struct {
/* these are hardcoded - don't touch */
  volatile long        state;          /* -1 unrunnable, 0 runnable, >0 stopped */
  long                 counter;
  long                 priority;
  unsigned             long signal;
  unsigned             long blocked;   /* bitmap of masked signals */
  unsigned             long flags;     /* per process flags, defined below */
  int errno;
  long                 debugreg[8];    /* Hardware debugging registers */
  struct exec_domain   *exec_domain;
/* various fields */
  struct linux_binfmt  *binfmt;
  struct task_struct   *next_task, *prev_task;
  struct task_struct   *next_run,  *prev_run;
  unsigned long        saved_kernel_stack;
  unsigned long        kernel_stack_page;
  int                  exit_code, exit_signal;
  /* ??? */
  unsigned long        personality;
  int                  dumpable:1;
  int                  did_exec:1;
  int                  pid;
  int                  pgrp;
  int                  tty_old_pgrp;
  int                  session;
  /* boolean value for session group leader */
  int                  leader;
  int                  groups[NGROUPS];
  /* 
   * pointers to (original) parent process, youngest child, younger sibling,
   * older sibling, respectively.  (p->father can be replaced with 
   * p->p_pptr->pid)
   */
  struct task_struct   *p_opptr, *p_pptr, *p_cptr, 
                       *p_ysptr, *p_osptr;
  struct wait_queue    *wait_chldexit;  
  unsigned short       uid,euid,suid,fsuid;
  unsigned short       gid,egid,sgid,fsgid;
  unsigned long        timeout, policy, rt_priority;
  unsigned long        it_real_value, it_prof_value, it_virt_value;
  unsigned long        it_real_incr, it_prof_incr, it_virt_incr;
  struct timer_list    real_timer;
  long                 utime, stime, cutime, cstime, start_time;
/* mm fault and swap info: this can arguably be seen as either
   mm-specific or thread-specific */
  unsigned long        min_flt, maj_flt, nswap, cmin_flt, cmaj_flt, cnswap;
  int swappable:1;
  unsigned long        swap_address;
  unsigned long        old_maj_flt;    /* old value of maj_flt */
  unsigned long        dec_flt;        /* page fault count of the last time */
  unsigned long        swap_cnt;       /* number of pages to swap on next pass */
/* limits */
  struct rlimit        rlim[RLIM_NLIMITS];
  unsigned short       used_math;
  char                 comm[16];
/* file system info */
  int                  link_count;
  struct tty_struct    *tty;           /* NULL if no tty */
/* ipc stuff */
  struct sem_undo      *semundo;
  struct sem_queue     *semsleeping;
/* ldt for this task - used by Wine.  If NULL, default_ldt is used */
  struct desc_struct *ldt;
/* tss for this task */
  struct thread_struct tss;
/* filesystem information */
  struct fs_struct     *fs;
/* open file information */
  struct files_struct  *files;
/* memory management info */
  struct mm_struct     *mm;
/* signal handlers */
  struct signal_struct *sig;
#ifdef __SMP__
  int                  processor;
  int                  last_processor;
  int                  lock_depth;     /* Lock depth. 
                                          We can context switch in and out
                                          of holding a syscall kernel lock... */  
#endif   
};
```

Comment: From the question above: `What purpose does this structure serve ?`