# How to get pagetable of process for MMU of DMA in Linux

Tags: linux, driver, fpga, mmu, dpdk

How to get pagetable of process for MMU of DMA in Linux?

(For DPDK app, custom DMA, custom MMU in FPGA, Zynq-7020/US+, Linux 4.6+, MMU of DMA is bounded to single process)

Task_struct of process can be obtained by kernel module which can access it by "current" as mentioned [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346545/what-is-structure-pointer-current-pointing-to-in-linux-kernel-code).

I see `struct mm_struct *mm, *active_mm;` on line 1549
in [struct task_struct (line 1475)](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h).

I think that page table pointer must be there but I can not see it.

Does anyone know where it is stored?

Comment: Does anyone know wheremeanings of fields in mm_context struct, (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/include/asm/mmu.h#L34) can be found?

Comment: DPDK apps use /proc/pagemap to read the page table, don't they?

Comment: Yes they do, but it is list of mapped pages, page table would has to be built manually. 
(Problem is that hugepages are not supported on old ARMs like A9 and MMU has to operate with 4k pages as well. Because of this pagemap is not enough and MMU for DMA has to be more complicated. But if anyone knows better solution I would be glad to know too.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Say your processor doesn't support huge pages but the DMA engine does. What does that have to do with what API you use to read the page table? In any case, are you interested with the kernel API to walk the page tables?

Comment: I wrote it wrong, sorry. Huge pages are not supported and that's all.

Yes I am interested in kernel API to walk the page tables. I tried to look at arch/arm/mm/* in linux kernel but I cant find where is page table for task_struct created and how can be accessed.